# Problem in Divisibility and Functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $ n $ is an integer, $ A $ is the set of $ n $'s divisors and $ f :A\rightarrow A $ be a function with this property: if $ a $ and $ b $ belong to $ A $ and $ a\mid b $, then $ f (a)\mid f (b) $. Prove that there is an integer $m$ in $ A $ that $f (m)=m $.

Comment: Do you mean "there is an integer $m$ [instead of $n$] in $A$ such that $f(m) = m$"?

Comment: Assuming that is so, is $1 \in A$?  Is $n \in A$?

Comment: Try $m= f^{\infty}(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a prime number than it is clear, because either $f$ is constant or the identity.

If $n$ is not a prime number:Assume that f does not have a fixed point and  let $f(1) = m$. Then we can define $f'$ for $n/m$ by $f'(k) = f(k)/m$ for all divisors $k$ of $n/m$. Since $f$ has no fixed point, also $f'$ has no fixed point. Inductively we will arrive at a prime and get a contradiction.

Comment: Likely I'm just missing something - why does the identity not also satisfy this condition if $n$ is not prime?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If f is the identity, it clearly has a fixed point...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, you said in your answer that if $n$ is prime, the statement is clear because $f$ can be the identity, but then used induction to show the statement follows when $n$ is not prime. It isn't clear to me why we can't simply say $f$ is the identity even when $n$ is not prime.

Comment: because we assume that f does not have a fixed point.

Comment: Ah, I misread the point of the statement, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

We have $1 \mid f(1) \mid f^2(1) \mid f^3(1) \mid \cdots$

Since $A$ is finite, this sequence must repeat: $f^{j+p}(1)=f^j(1)$, for some $j \ge 0$ and $p \ge 1$.

Since $f$ is increasing, we must have $p=1$, if $p$ is the minimal period.

Then $m=f^j(1)$ is a fixed point of $f$: $f(m)=m$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is clearly increasing. So you can use the fact that an increasing function from $A$ to $A$ must have a fixpoint.

Let $ B = \{ x \in A \mid f(x) > x \}$. If $B$ is empty, then $1 \not\in B$ thus $f(1) \leq 1$ but since $f(1)$ must be in $A$ too, $f(1) \geq 1$ and thus $m=1$ do the job.

Otherwise, you can consider $m = max(B)$, then $f(f(m)) \geq f(m) > m$ because $f$ is increasing and $m \in B$. Now assume $f(f(m)) > f(m)$, then $f(m)$ would be in $B$ with $f(m) > m = max(B)$ : this is a contradiction. Hence, $f(f(m)) \leq f(m)$ and $f(m)$ is the fixpoint you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you intended to say that "... there is an integer $m$ ...", as @BrianTung pointed out.

However, the statement then isn't true.  Take $n=1,$ so that $A = \lbrace 1,-1 \rbrace.$ Define $f(x)=-x$ for a counterexample.

I suspect that the problem was intended to be about *positive* integers.

Comment: What's with the downvote?  Maybe it seems like I was being picky, but the problem was incorrect as stated, and that ought to be pointed out.